# Flyway fails to detect new migration files

Tags: java, gradle, flyway

I'm trying to run the `flywayMigrate` task from Gradle in my project after adding a new migration file but Flyway doesn't pick it up. I get this output:

```
Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb (PostgreSQL 10.6)
Successfully validated 6 migrations (execution time 00:00.105s)
Current version of schema "public": 5
Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

So it detects that I have **6** migrations but it doesn't execute the new file I just added (`V6`) and insists on saying that the schema is up to date even if it isn't.

This is how my config looks like:

```
{
    url = database_url
    user = database_user
    password = database_password
    driver = database_driver
    schemas = ["public"]
    locations = ["filesystem:shared/src/main/resources/db/migration"]
    table = "flyway_schema_history"
    sqlMigrationPrefix = "V"
    sqlMigrationSuffix = ".sql"
    placeholderPrefix = "\${"
    placeholderSuffix = "}"
    target = "5.1"
}
```

I checked every setting and it is ok, It picks up the first **5** migration files if I delete all tables but for some reason the **6**th one is not picked up. *(I even tried adding a 7th one but it is not working either)*

I tried to run the `sql` in the 6th migration file and it runs OK so there is probably a problem with Flyway.

If I run with the `debug` flag I can see that it even parses and reads out the sql from the file but all migrations are filtered out. What am I doing wrong?

```
...
15:23:34.893 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.SqlScript] Parsing V5__some_migration_5.sql ...
15:23:34.893 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.SqlScript] Found statement at line 1: ...
...
15:23:34.894 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.SqlScript] Parsing V6__some_migration_6.sql ...
15:23:34.894 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.SqlScript] Found statement at line 1: ...
15:23:34.894 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner] Filtering out resource: shared/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__some_migration_1.sql (filename: V1__some_migration_1.sql)
15:23:34.895 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner] Filtering out resource: shared/src/main/resources/db/migration/V2__some_migration_2.sql (filename: V2__some_migration_2.sql)
15:23:34.895 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner] Filtering out resource: shared/src/main/resources/db/migration/V3__some_migration_3.sql (filename: V3__some_migration_3.sql)
15:23:34.895 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner] Filtering out resource: shared/src/main/resources/db/migration/V4__some_migration_4.sql (filename: V4__some_migration_4.sql)
15:23:34.895 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner] Filtering out resource: shared/src/main/resources/db/migration/V5__some_migration_5.sql (filename: V5__some_migration_5.sql)
15:23:34.895 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner] Filtering out resource: shared/src/main/resources/db/migration/V6__some_migration_6.sql (filename: V6__some_migration_6.sql)
15:23:34.899 [DEBUG] [org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection]   setAutoCommit = true
15:23:34.899 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate] Successfully validated 6 migrations (execution time 00:00.016s)
15:23:34.899 [DEBUG] [org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection]   setAutoCommit = false
15:23:34.899 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbSchemas] Schema "public" already exists. Skipping schema creation.
15:23:34.900 [DEBUG] [org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection]   setAutoCommit = true
15:23:34.915 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Current version of schema "public": 5
15:23:34.915 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

What I see in the `flyway_schema_history` is consistent with what the log says:

```
installed_rank  version description type    script  checksum    installed_by    installed_on    execution_time  success
1   1   some migration 1    SQL V1__some_migration_1.sql    1640479949  myuser  2019-05-31 15:17:19.354850  26  true
2   2   some migration 2    SQL V2__some_migration_2.sql    1463373644  myuser  2019-05-31 15:17:19.394065  1   true
3   3   some migration 3    SQL V3__some_migration_3.sql    1872028758  myuser  2019-05-31 15:17:19.398957  9   true
4   4   some migration 4    SQL V4__some_migration_4.sql    762610066   myuser  2019-05-31 15:17:19.410718  5   true
5   5   some migration 5    SQL V5__some_migration_5.sql    -355256115  myuser  2019-05-31 15:17:19.418077  1   true
```

Comment: Do all migration files follow the naming scheme?

Comment: What is in flayway_history table?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Really it's very strange... Take a look here - may be, this solution gives some ideas... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300233/flyway-for-existing-public-schema

Comment: This is different. I tried running with `--stacktrace` as well, but I get no exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:-)

You have `target = "5.1"` in your config, but

```
target  NO  latest version  

The target version up to which Flyway should run migrations. 
Migrations with a higher version number will not be applied. 
The string 'current' will be interpreted as MigrationVersion.CURRENT, 
a placeholder for the latest version that has been applied to the database.
```

Look at [Gradle Task: flywayMigrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/migrate)

This is why you cannot process migration > 5.1

Comment: @Hexworks Sometimes it happens :-) I was wondered too. Mark answer as solution, please. And have a nice day.